# A problem on algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Prove that if $A^n(\mathcal{K})$ is irreductible, then $\mathcal{K}$ is infinite.

I know that $A^n(\mathcal{K})$ is irreductible if and only if $I(A^n(\mathcal{K}))$ is a prime ideal of $\mathcal{K}[X_1,...,X_n]$. 
But how can I get from here that $I(A^n(\mathcal{K}))=\{0\}$, i.e. that $I(A^n(\mathcal{K}))$ is the unitary set of the zero polynomial?

Comment: I think the title could be more descriptive!

Answer (score 2):

If $K$ is finite with $q$ elements, you have $K^n = \cup_{i=1}^n V(f_i)$ where $f_i (T_1,\ldots,T_n) = T_i^q - T_i$, showing that your affine space $K^n$ is a union of proper closed subspaces, hence is not irreducible. Indeed, the very definition of being irreducible - before any algebraic formulation - is : not being writable as a finite union of proper closed subsets.